# Convert CSV to UTF-8 in Python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am trying to create a duplicate CSV without a header. When I attempt this I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1895: invalid start byte.
```

I've read the python `CSV` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) on `Unicode` and `UTF-8` encoding and have implemented it. 
However, my output file is being generated with no data in it. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
import csv

path =  '/Users/johndoe/file.csv'

with open(path, 'r') as infile, open(path + 'final.csv', 'w') as outfile:

    def unicode_csv(infile, outfile):
        inputs = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(infile))
        output = csv.writer(outfile)

        for index, row in enumerate(inputs):
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
            if index == 0:
                 continue
        output.writerow(row)

    def utf_8_encoder(infile):
        for line in infile:
            yield line.encode('utf-8')

unicode_csv(infile, outfile)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to simply include two additional parameters to the

```
with open(path, 'r') as infile:
```

The two parameters are encoding ='UTF-8' and errors='ignore'. This allowed me to create a duplicate of original CSV without the headers and without the UnicodeDecodeError. Below is the completed code.

```
import csv

path =  '/Users/johndoe/file.csv'

with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as infile, open(path + 'final.csv', 'w') as outfile:
     inputs = csv.reader(infile)
     output = csv.writer(outfile)

     for index, row in enumerate(inputs):
         # Create file with no header
         if index == 0:
             continue
         output.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the line

```
unicode_csv(infile,outfile)
```

isn't indented, it is out of the scope of the `with` command, and when it called, then infile and outfile are both closed.

The files should be opened when they are used, not when the functions are defined, so have:

```
with open(path, 'r') as infile, open(path + 'final.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    unicode_csv(infile,outfile)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use pandas, and you know the exact encoding of your file, you could try this:

```
import pandas as pd

path =  '/Users/johndoe/file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: I used chardet to get the encoding string and then applied this, worked for me, thanks